# How to dynamically set an if /or condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a vague idea of how I want to do this, but I am stuck. Would appreciate it if anyone can advise if I am in the right direction or should I try something else?

But in layman terms, I am thinking along the line, if array met conditions like `(array[0][2] == 'default' || array[0][2] == 'thailand')`, I will get a new array of `[true, false, false, true, ...]` and then with the new true/false array, I will use it to filter the array based on index if it's false?

```
array = array.filter(function(e) { 
  if ( array[0][2] == 'default' ||  array[0][2] == 'thailand' ) { 
    return e 
  } 
})
```

Below are more details:

```
 var array = [
    [9117.0, 5184.0, default, Chair, 0.0, th, in|ae, false, men], 
    [9117.0, 5184.0, indonesia, television, 0.0, id, in|ae, false, men], 
    [9117.0, 5184.0, indonesia, television, 82.0, sg, in|ae, false, men], 
    [9431.0, 5456.0, default, television, 0.0, au, , false, men], 
    [9431.0, 5456.0, default, television, 0.0, au, , true, men], 
    [9431.0, 5456.0, default, television, 0.0, th, , false, men], 
    [9431.0, 5456.0, default, television, 0.0, th, , true, men], 
    [9431.0, 5456.0, default, television, 94.0, sg, , true, men], 
    [9431.0, 5456.0, default, television, 0.0, id, , false, men], 
    [9431.0, 5456.0, default, television, 0.0, id, , true, men], 
    [9431.0, 5456.0, thailand, television, 94.0, sg, , false, men], 
    [9152.0, 5225.0, default, drawer, 0.0, th, in|ae, false, men], 
    [9152.0, 5225.0, default, television, 70.0, sg, in|ae, false, men], 
    [9152.0, 5225.0, default, television, 0.0, id, in|ae, false, men], 
    [9152.0, 5225.0, default, television, 4.0, au, in|ae, false, men], 
    [9221.0, 5335.0, indonesia, television, 0.0, th, in|ae, false, men], 
    [9221.0, 5335.0, indonesia, television, 2.0, au, in|ae, false, men], 
    [9221.0, 5335.0, default, television, 0.0, id, in|ae, false, men], 
    [9221.0, 5335.0, default, drawer, 0.0, sg, in|ae, false, men]
  ]
```

Do I need an array with arrays where (filter1 && filter2 && filter3) are present?

```
var filter1= [['default'], ['thailand']] //if ( array[0][2] == 'default' ||  array[0][2] == 'thailand' ) => true
var filter2 = [['television']] //if ( array[0][3] == 'television' ) =>true
var filer3 = [['true']] //if ( array[0][7] == 'true' ) => true
```

Expected answer:

```
var answer = [
  [9431.0, 5456.0, default, television, 0.0, au, , true, men], 
  [9431.0, 5456.0, default, television, 0.0, th, , true, men], 
  [9431.0, 5456.0, default, television, 94.0, sg, , true, men], 
  [9431.0, 5456.0, default, television, 0.0, id, , true, men], 
  [9431.0, 5456.0, thailand, television, 94.0, sg, , true, men], 
]
```

Comment: the question is too broad.

Comment: you trying to split into 3 arrays or you want 1 array to contain all the rows that match any of the filters or 1 array to contain all the row that match all the filters?

Comment: @TomMendelson i need 1 array to contain all the row that match all the filters

Comment: Start simple. write your code to filter your input only based on filter 1. Then filter that result with filter 2, and then filter that result with filter 3. Then, refactor your code to filter for each item in an array of filters. then work on how to supply valid filters to that array. You're going to need to pair each filter with the appropriate index it should be checked against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this:

first, define your filters (note, the filters are functions that return true\false)

```
var filter1 = obj => obj[0][2] === 'default' || obj[0][2] === 'thailand';
var filter2 = obj => // do the filter
var filter3 = obj => // do the filter

var filters = [filter1, filter2, filter3]
```

and then, when you filtering the data you recicved do something like that:

```
array.filter(x => filters.every(f => f(x))
```

in this approach, your code would look much simpler, it would be easier to add \ remove filters and you would have the ability to make some changes easily.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your filter, you need to use the parameter, not the array itself.

Also, you need to return true or false, not the elemnts. Like this:

```
array = array.filter(function(e) { 
    if ( e[2] == 'default' ||  e[2] == 'indonesia' ) { 
       return true;
    }
    return false;
})
```